# Calculus of variations and envelope theorem application

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, envelope

My Euler-Lagrange equation is a non-linear differential equation and I am convinced that it cannot be expressed in a closed-form solution.

My question is: 
Is there a theorem in the calculus of variations which is similar to the envelope theorem that we use in a static environment?

1) I want to show that my maximized value (with a solution function) increases with a parameter.

2) I want to show that the derivative of choice variable with respect to a parameter is always positive without solving the DE.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, there exist dynamical extensions of the [envelope theorem for static systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem), say, a functional
$$S[q; \alpha]~=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! \mathrm{d}t~L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t; \alpha)  $$
in case of [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints)$^1$
$$\chi(q(t);\alpha)~=~0.$$
Here $\alpha$ are external parameters.
The extended functional reads
$$\widetilde{S}[q,\lambda; \alpha]~=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! \mathrm{d}t~\widetilde{L}(q(t),\lambda(t),\dot{q}(t),t; \alpha),$$ 
$$ \widetilde{L}(q(t),\lambda(t),\dot{q}(t),t; \alpha)~=~L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t; \alpha) ~+~\lambda(t) \chi(q(t);\alpha), $$
where $\lambda$ are [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

In this dynamical situation the [envelope theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem) becomes
$$ \frac{d^{\rm tot} S[q^{\ast}(\alpha); \alpha]}{d\alpha}~=~\frac{d^{\rm tot} \widetilde{S}[q^{\ast}(\alpha),\lambda^{\ast}(\alpha); \alpha]}{d\alpha}
~=~\frac{\partial^{\rm expl} \widetilde{S}[q^{\ast}(\alpha),\lambda^{\ast}(\alpha); \alpha]}{\partial\alpha}.$$
The proof is a straightforward application of [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for constrained systems, and derivatives thereof, e.g.
 $$\frac{d^{\rm tot} \chi(q^{\ast}(t;\alpha);\alpha)}{d\alpha}~=~0.$$

--

$^1$ Here I'm thinking of 2-sided constraints for simplicity. I haven't thought about whether it can be extended to 1-sided constraints (i.e. inequalities) as on the Wikipedia page. I also avoid $\dot{q}$-dependent constraints $\chi$ as they would make the Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$ dynamical.

Comment: What does the envelope maximize or minimize? Please give one geometric example, including $(\alpha,\lambda)$. If possible with reference to Dido's problem..

Comment: I guess the constraint is about the initial point that I assume. So, basically given the last equation, by fixing some t, we can just take a partial derivative of objective function inside the integrand with respect to alpha (just like we do in static envelop theorem). Am I getting correctly?

Comment: I edited my original question. Could you give a little hint for the second? Would there be a connection between having an answer for the second and your answer?